# “Bent 90 degrees” or “at 90 degrees”?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

> The metal bar was straight. But I bent it to make a right (90 degrees) angle.

Can I say it as below?

1. The metal bar was bent 90 *degrees*.
   (90 *degree* / **at** 90 degree / **to** 90 degree)
2. 90 *degree* / *degrees* bending of the metal bar was conducted.

Comment: I can't find any reference to support it but I, as a British English speaker, would usually say "bent through 90" or "bent at a 90 degree angle". The logic behind the "bent through" expression is that the part of the bar which is bent passes through all the angles between 0 and 90 degrees to the rest of the bar before it reaches its final inclination.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the pluralisation: when "90 degree(s)" is used as a noun it will be pluralised ("90 degrees", when used as an adjective it will be singular ("a 90 degree angle").

On the basis that you bent the bar yourself, it appears your sentence 1 is describing what you did, rather than describing the bar (*bent* is both the past participle and an adjective). In this case it is fine without a preposition. You could also use "to", describing the limit of the bending you carried out; or "through", describing the "distance" you bent it. You should not use "at"; this would only apply if *bent* was an adjective.

In your second example you are using "90 degree" as an adjective to describe the bending. It is therefore "90 degree bending". The whole sentence sounds unnatural or unidiomatic to me though.

---

(*Source: Experience as a native speaker. I have no idea where to start research to back up my assertions.*)